# Configuring exposed web service resources when using Quarkus

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus

I have a multi-module project using Quarkus with RESTEasy. One module currently contains implementations of different webservice endpoints, i.e.:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {}

@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/bar")
public class BarResource {}
```

The module contains a `beans.xml` file and is processed by Quarkus to enable CDI.

I would like to consume this module from one or more other modules, but selectively expose the endpoints.

I.e. `FooApplication` exposes the `/foo` endpoint and `BarApplication` exposes the /`bar` endpoint. If I just create a Quarkus/RESTEasy-application with a dependency on the other module, it always exposes both endpoints and I can't seem to find any way to control this. I could move `FooResource` to `FooApplication` and `BarResource` to `BarApplication`, but I would like to avoid this.

Is it possible to control which resources Quarkus/RESTEasy exposes (either at compile-time or at runtime)?

Comment: In most web frameworks that I use, routes are not automatically added... Is quarkus different? I feel like the problem lies in the `beans.xml` file. Can you add it?

Comment: @cricket_007 It looks like Quarkus/RESTEasy automatically adds all resources annotated with \@Produces. Quarkus ignores the contents of beans.xml, but mine is identical to this one: https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee8-samples/blob/master/cdi/events-async/src/test/resources/beans.xml

Comment: I highly doubt its `@Produces`. I would believe `@Path`, but I know from Dropwizard's or Jersey's JAX-RS , you need to manually hook up the Resource classes into the Application servlet container

Comment: Yes, sorry. @Path. Looks like the magic happens here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/resteasy-server-common/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/resteasy/server/common/deployment/ResteasyServerCommonProcessor.java#L233 but I can't seem to find a way to exclude classes from the automatic bean detection.

Comment: Might be worth making a PR like `disabledPaths` config object, then filter out this list https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/resteasy-server-common/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/resteasy/server/common/deployment/ResteasyServerCommonProcessor.java#L195